# How to deny access to certain routes / views for users

Tags: laravel, view, authorization, acl, laravel-5

I am trying to deny access for users other than the one with **id=1** (in my case it's admin) to 'cpanel' (admin panel) view. I was trying to achieve this with ACL, but somehow I think that this is not the most correct way.

This is what I want to do in pseudocode version

```
if (isAdmin())
    renderPage()
else
    print "You are not allowed to view this page"
```

Reading documentation I found this line declared in custom Controller

```
$this->authorize('update', $post);
```

where 'update' is an ability defined elsewhere, and the $post seems to always be a model (use App\Post) that I don't know how to implement. I don't think that Laravel's documentation covers how to implement models for authorization.

How can I authorize a view? It's Laravel 5.2

Comment: Have you looked into middleware? What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am new to middleware, but I made some simple auths with web middleware to register / login / view / edit / remove users. It's Laravel 5.2. I will read a little more about it now.

Comment: The documentation is actually pretty clear on how to implement this. Read the [Define Abilities](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#defining-abilities) section to understand how that works first. The models require no special changes for this to work, they're regular Eloquent models. Then you can use a myriad of ways to check if a user is permitted a defined ability: `$request->user()->can('update', $post)`, or `Gate::allows('update', $post)`, or as you mentioned `$this->authorize('update', $post);`.